# Baking textures usefull to shorten render times?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, texture-baking, baking

So I always thought that bakingtextures is just for assets that you want to export for games but now I have read somewhere that it also helps a lot with render times. My Laptop explodes everytime I render something and I only use max 50 samples because otherwise it never finishes. Should I bake my textures?

Answer (score 2):

Yes that's actually what is recommended by the [documentation](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.79/render/blender_render/optimizations/performance.html).
[image]